# Wiring Boiler for a C wire Adapter

Tags: thermostat-c-wire, boiler

I want to install a smart thermostat for one of my boiler zones. My thermostat doesn't have a C wire. It looks like installing an adapter would be the best option, but I am not sure my system is compatible. I see reviews for the Honeywell thermostat say it can work with boilers though. This is what my system looks like. Can anyone verify that a C wire adapter would work in my situation?

Yellow/black wires = R and Red/Green = W/Aux

Big green and red wires coming from transformer. The other red and green wires leaving the transformer head out through the wall.

Edit: 3 zones, but I would like to just update one zone's thermostats for the time being. Here is the links to the [zone valves](https://www.supplyhouse.com/Honeywell-Home-40003916-026-Replacement-Head-for-V8043E-Zone-Valves). The boiler is a Peerless from 1992. I don't have any or see any schematics.

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add to the question: 1) A picture of your furnace wiring schematic taken from its case, door, or manual. 2) State if you have a zone controller, and if so a photo of that and its schematic, 3) A better description or pictures of how and where all those 4-wire telephone cables go.

Comment: That said, in all likeliness the left screw of that transformer on the wall is probably your C terminal ... probably a reasonable approach to just try it.  You'll have to split out one of the always-paired wires to that specific thermostat in order to free a wire up for this.

Comment: What make/model is your furnace?

Comment: It is a boiler. A 92 Peerless.

Comment: @jay613 - I got a better view of the transformer and the red wire is attached to the C terminal. I wonder if I could move one of the wires that is twisted together and use that as the C? Seems strange to have two wires attached to the same terminals.